# Enabling only keyboard or mouse to wake PC enables both

Tags: windows, wake-up, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

In device manager, If I enable only the keyboard or mouse with the `Allow this device to wake the computer` option, it makes both the keyboard AND mouse wake the PC. And of course, enabling both at the same time reproduces this behavior.

I'm using the following:

1. MK330 Logitech wireless keyboard
2. M510 Logitech wireless mouse
3. Windows 10 Pro (1909 version)

The keyboard and mouse are both connected to the same unifying receiver. I want only the keyboard to wake the PC. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: From perspective of your Windows system the receiver is the "device" (check Windows Device Manager it it allows you to configure each device individually) But AFAIK you can't configure mouse and keyboard individually in this set-up.

Comment: I was afraid of this. I used both receivers. All is OK now. Thanks.